# DAX function equivalent to FINV

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, probability-distribution

I'm looking for a DAX function equivalent to the FINV function in excel which calculates the inverse of the F probability distribution given a probability, numerator and denominator degrees of freedom.

I've searched through the official list of DAX statistical functions, but I could not find any function that does this. Can someone help?

Comment: I got a solution in terms of BETA.INV function.